# Display posts for a single post format

Tags: posts, post-formats, paths

I saw a a url path to display all posts of a particular 'format' a few weeks ago, but I've lost the link. Does anyone know the path?

It will be something like

> mywebsitex.com/format/image

**Works on a standard WP install**

> mywebsitex.com/type/image/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The post format taxonomy:

The *post format* is a default taxonomy, registered with:

```
register_taxonomy( 'post_format', 'post', array(
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => _x( 'Format', 'post format' ),
                    'singular_name' => _x( 'Format', 'post format' ),
            ),
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => $rewrite['post_format'],
            'show_ui' => false,
            '_builtin' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => current_theme_supports( 'post-formats' ),
    ) );
```

where

```
$rewrite['post_format'] = $post_format_base ? array( 'slug' => $post_format_base ):false;
```

and

```
$post_format_base = apply_filters( 'post_format_rewrite_base', 'type' );
```

Note that the taxonomy slug is  `post_format` and the rewrite slug is `type`.

### The post format terms:

We can see the available post formats from the `get_post_format_strings()` function:

```
/**
 * Returns an array of post format slugs to their translated and pretty display versions
 * 
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @return array The array of translated post format names.
 */
function get_post_format_strings() {
        $strings = array(
                'standard' => _x( 'Standard', 'Post format' ), // Special case. any value that evals to false will be considered standard
                'aside'    => _x( 'Aside',    'Post format' ),
                'chat'     => _x( 'Chat',     'Post format' ),
                'gallery'  => _x( 'Gallery',  'Post format' ),
                'link'     => _x( 'Link',     'Post format' ),
                'image'    => _x( 'Image',    'Post format' ),
                'quote'    => _x( 'Quote',    'Post format' ),
                'status'   => _x( 'Status',   'Post format' ),
                'video'    => _x( 'Video',    'Post format' ),   
                'audio'    => _x( 'Audio',    'Post format' ),
        );
        return $strings;
}
```

The terms have the slug `post-format-{$format}` where `$format` can be one of:

```
aside, chat, gallery, link, image, quote, status, video, audio
```

where `standard` is not included.

### The post format rewrite rules:

Here you can see the corresponding generated rewrite rules:

[image: Rewrite Rules]

according to the *Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer*.

### The post format public queries:

We can therefore use the following public queries:

```
http://example.tld/type/post-format-aside/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-chat/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-gallery/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-link/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-image/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-quote/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-status/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-video/
http://example.tld/type/post-format-audio/
```

to display all posts in a given post format.

### Update:

@ToddBenrud said he managed to get:

```
http://example.tld/type/image/
```

to work.

The reason for that is the following `request` filter:

```
/**
 * Filters the request to allow for the format prefix.
 *
 * @access private
 * @since 3.1.0
 */
function _post_format_request( $qvs ) {
        if ( ! isset( $qvs['post_format'] ) )
                return $qvs;
        $slugs = get_post_format_slugs();
        if ( isset( $slugs[ $qvs['post_format'] ] ) )
                $qvs['post_format'] = 'post-format-' . $slugs[ $qvs['post_format'] ];
        $tax = get_taxonomy( 'post_format' );
        if ( ! is_admin() )
                $qvs['post_type'] = $tax->object_type;
        return $qvs;
}
add_filter( 'request', '_post_format_request' );
```

This means that a request with the query variable:

```
Array
(
    [post_format] => image
)
```

is modified to the correct term name:

```
Array
(
    [post_format] => post-format-image
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => post
        )
)
```

So we could also use:

```
http://example.tld/type/aside/
http://example.tld/type/chat/
http://example.tld/type/gallery/
http://example.tld/type/link/
http://example.tld/type/image/
http://example.tld/type/quote/
http://example.tld/type/status/
http://example.tld/type/video/
http://example.tld/type/audio/
```

Comment: I think this line, `'standard' => _x( 'Standard', 'Post format' ),` confuses many people :-). Had a slight quarrel with someone in the week about this. `standard` is not a post format, but just a fall back if no post format is selected for the specific post. I think your post also enforces this point

Comment: yes this can be rather confusing ;-) Since this is a non-hierarchial taxonomy, we could also rename `'Standard'` to `'No post format'` and it would be a waste to add such a term to each post, as far as I understand it.